# External JS file not working within my HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

New to JS, working on a D3 visualization and when I server my html file that has the JS script:

```
<script src="visualization.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I end up getting this error message:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) visualization.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server
>   responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I've tried the following proposed solutions that I found on this site and others but nothing seems to work. I've tried:

- Making the path more detailed by trying Map1/visualization.js and other variations of this with the correct directories.
- Clearing the Cache and all browsing data.
- Placing the js file inside the same directory as your HTML file (did that from the start)

Anyone know a solution? Not sure what is wrong.

My html file code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset= "utf-8">
    <style>
        *{
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue";

        }
        p {
            font-size: 0.85em;

        }
        svg {
            background: #efefef;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- Socket io !-->
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> 

    <!-- D3 Link !-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Topojson library !-->
    <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Visualization file -->
    <script src="visualization.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

All my files for this project are inside the directory Map1.

```
Map1:
  -map1.html
  -package.json
  -server1.js -> the file to that serves my html file
  -visualization.js
  -world.topojson``
```

Comment: add your HTML Code with js reference &  folder structure

Comment: Are you using Node.js to serve the files? What command did you use to start the webserver?

Comment: You can remove `type="text/javascript"`, by the way. `<script>` tags already use `text/javascript` as their default `type`, making this attribute's inclusion redundant.

Comment: Yeah I am using Node.Js to serve the files. These are the commands that I am using:   npm install --save express@4.15.2 -> npm install --save socket.io ->
npm i nodemon -g -> nodemod Map1/server1.js. The js file were I use Node.js to server the html file is inside the same directory as my html file and the js file that gives me the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Step 1**

Firstly, Make Sure that your Java Script file `visualization.js` is still exists or check that according to you,`visualization.js` should located in the same directory which your html file located.

**2. Step 2**

But if it isn't thats the reason for getting 404 error,I recommend you to
check the directory which your `visualization.js` file currently exists.

Try this;

Eg:- `<script src="directory/visualization.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

In here I mean by `directory` is the directory what your `visualization.js` is currently located.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're running the server from a different working directory to where the HTML/JS files are stored. If you have this directory structure:

```
app
 └── static
      ├── index.html
      └── visualization.js
```

... and you've launched the server from the `app` directory, then the browser will be looking for `visualization.js` here:

```
app
 ├── static
 │    └── ...
 │   
 ├── index.html
 └── visualization.js <-
```

Make sure you're running the server from the same directory which contains the `visualization.js`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few:

1. try putting the './visualization.js' in src.
2. Check the spelling.
3. Put this line at the end of the  tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an npm package [assets](https://www.npmjs.com/package/assets).

After using it you may use method `resolver.path()`.

**Now, instead of writing this:**

```
var url = '/assets/images/icons/create.png';
```

**You can write this:**

```
var url = resolver.path('icons/create.png');
```